# .Net MVC Publish error - Copying file template\hts-cache\doit.log to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\template\hts-cache\doit.log failed

Tags: visual-studio, templates, publish

When trying to publish the project to a local folder, this error shows up, this is the first time to get the error, I have published many projects before.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Copying file template\hts-cache\doit.log to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\template\hts-cache\doit.log failed. Could not find file 'template\hts-cache\doit.log'.   Expenditure     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solution Explorer -> click on show All Files Icon.

If there is any files with yellow mark, probably with an exclamation yellow mark(alert symbol).

If so, right click on that and include it if required. Else exclude it and then publish.

[image]